# Using ampersand in liquid template stops compiling it

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm using Jekyll and wants to add UTM tags to URLs. When editing `feed.xml` file, adding `&` to the query string breaks the file to be compiled.

This is not working:

```
<link href="http://somedomain.com/?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=page" />
```

However, this is working

```
<link href="http://somedomain.com/?utm_source=twitter" />
```

I have tested this and any ampersand character in the file causes this problem.

How to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, I should use `&amp;` instead:

```
<link href="http://somedomain.com/?utm_source=twitter&amp;utm_medium=page" />
```